# Node.js script does not end when using await on sequelize.athenticate()

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

This is the code I'm using to start Sequelize and authenticate. I need to await the authenticate() method to make sure database is ready to be used by other app components:

```
'use strict';

(async () =>
{
    let Sequelize=require('sequelize');
    let seq = new Sequelize('admin_apptoolset', 'root', 'root', 
        {
            host: 'localhost',
            dialect: 'mysql',
            operatorsAliases: false,
            pool: 
            {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                acquire: 30000,
                idle: 10000
            }
        });

        console.log("Trying to connect to database...");
        await seq.authenticate();
        console.log("Connected to database...");

        return;
})()
```

I can see how both console logs are dumped to the console but the process doesn't exit after the return. Shouldn't it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disconnect from database, because it's prevent event loot from exit.
Add `seq.close();` before `return`;

```
(async () => {
    let Sequelize = require("sequelize");
    let seq = new Sequelize("admin_apptoolset", "root", "root", {
        host: "localhost",
        dialect: "mysql",
        operatorsAliases: false,
        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        }
    });
    console.log("Trying to connect to database...");
    await seq.authenticate();
    console.log("Connected to database...");
    seq.close(); // close connection
    return;
})();
```